# Malloc array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, heap-memory

I've been looking around for the past few days on and off about how to allocate memory to an array of structs. I have tried most of the examples online with no success, read through the book 'The C programming language' with no success.

```
typedef struct {
    int testMallocOne;
    int testMallocTwo;
} test;
```

This is where I have set my struct.

I then declared my struct using -

```
struct test _testData[5];
```

and this is where I'm stuck - this is the latest attempt I have made which has been unsuccessful

```
_testData = malloc (sizeof(struct test);
```

Could anyone point out where I am going wrong, as from my research I seem to be doing the same as most examples I have seen. These are all declared outside of main.

Comment: firstly, you need a closing parenthesis for`malloc` :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
struct test _testData[5];  // You already declared it an array
```

to dynamically allocate array

```
struct test *_testData = malloc(5 * sizeof(struct test));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct test _testData[5];
```

You have already allocated memory for 5 objects of type `struct test` on stack.

If you want to allocate memory dynamically

Then do

```
struct test * ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test) * 5);
```

The memory allocated is on heap in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use something like:

```
test *_testData = malloc (5 * sizeof(*_testData));
```

Since you create a `typedef`, there's no real need to specify the full structure name and the multiplication by five automatically gives you an array of the desired size.

You'll notice I've also used `*_testData` as the argument to `sizeof` - it's by no means necessary but it minimises the changes required should you change the type to something else in future.

Answer (score 1):

This needs more context, but when you do

```
struct test _testData[5];
```

you're allocating memory on the stack, so you don't need malloc. Should you use malloc, you'd define your variable as a pointer, request a chunk of memory that would allocate your entire array and assign the pointer to it:

```
struct test *_testData;  
_testData = malloc(5 * sizeof(struct test));
```

Answer (score 0):

- To use `struct test _testData[5];`

  ```
  struct test _testData[5];
  // to malloc
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(_testData)/sizeof(_testData[0]); i++)
      _testData[i] = malloc (sizeof(struct test));

  // do something to _testData[0],_testData[1]... 
  // to free
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(_testData)/sizeof(_testData[0]); i++)
      if(_testData[i]) {
          free (_testData[i])
      };
  ```
- To use `struct test *p;`

  ```
  struct test *p;
  int num = 5;
  // to malloc
  p = malloc (sizeof(struct test)*num);
  // do something to p[0],p[1]...
  // to free
  if(p){
     free(p);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc` for creating a pointer to the array of 5 `struct test` items in heap dynamically:

```
struct test *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test) * 5);
```

and you must free the pointer after its use to prevent **memory leaks**.

While your code statement:

```
struct test _testData[5];
```

allocates the fixed memory to the array of `struct test` items in the stack. This will be automatically de-allocated by the compiler after its use.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Hope this small prog will help you to understand */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct test
{
        int testMallocOne;
        int testMallocTwo;
} test; 

typedef struct test node;

int main ( void )
{
        int i=0;
        node *ptr[5];

        for ( i=0; i<5 ; i++ )
        {
                ptr[i] = malloc (sizeof (node ));
        }
        for ( i=0; i<5; i++ )
        {
                printf ("\n enter the value for testMallocOne " );
                scanf ( "%d", &(ptr[i]->testMallocOne) );

                printf ("\n enter the value for testMallocTwo " );
                scanf ( "%d", &(ptr[i]->testMallocTwo) );

        }

        printf ( "\n here is the data \n");

        for ( i=0; i<5; i++ )
        {
                printf ( "\n value of i = %d and testMallocOne is  %d",i, ptr[i]->testMallocOne );
                printf ( "\n value of i = %d and testMallocTwo is  %d",i, ptr[i]->testMallocTwo );
        }

        return ( 0 );
}
```